# ¿Cómo envio String xml por SoapUi, probar Webservice?

Tags: c#, webservice, soapui

Buenas, tengo entendido que con SoapUi se prueban los webservices así que estoy tratando de probar uno pero sin éxito, me explico... el siguiente webservice tiene donde poner los parámetros de búsqueda y funciona bien pues tiene los campos xml en la ventana de request del SoapUi. (0 problemas en este WS)

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:ConsultaInd>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:datosConsulta>
            <tem:tipoId>1</tem:tipoId>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:numId>10100956</tem:numId>
         </tem:datosConsulta>
      </tem:ConsultaInd>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

El problema viene con este otro webservice: al que tengo el xml que me dieron para probar:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:prom="MyCompany">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <prom:FactuRecibos/>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

XML que debo consultar:

```
<Multiplecash>
   <BoletaPago>
      <NumeroReferencia>(...)</NumeroReferencia>
        <NumeroReferenciaAuxiliar>(...)</NumeroReferenciaAuxiliar>
        <FechaEmision>...</FechaEmision>
        (... mas etiquetas xml)                       
   </BoletaPago>
</Multiplecash>
```

La pregunta es: ¿qué hago con ese XML donde lo pego? porque me da error si lo pongo solo, si lo pongo dentro de soapenv:Body, no se como ingresar ese parámetro para probar probé algo así y no tira.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:prom="MyCompany">
       <soap:Header/>
       <soap:Body>
          <prom:FactuRecibos>
<Multiplecash>
       <BoletaPago>
          <NumeroReferencia>(...)</NumeroReferencia>
            <NumeroReferenciaAuxiliar>(...)</NumeroReferenciaAuxiliar>
            <FechaEmision>...</FechaEmision>
            (... mas etiquetas xml)                       
       </BoletaPago>
    </Multiplecash>
          </prom:FactuRecibos>
       </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se trata de enviar un XML dentro de otro, puedes probar a usar el tag especial `<![CDATA[ ]]>`:

Todo lo que pongas en los corchetes internos será ignorado por el "parser" de XML, es decir, no se considerarán los posibles tags como algo que sea parte del XML contenedor:

```
 <soap:Body>
   <prom:FactuRecibos><![CDATA[ 
<Multiplecash>
  <BoletaPago>
    <NumeroReferencia>(...)</NumeroReferencia>
    <NumeroReferenciaAuxiliar>(...)</NumeroReferenciaAuxiliar>
    <FechaEmision>...</FechaEmision>
    (... mas etiquetas xml)                       
  </BoletaPago>
</Multiplecash> ]]>
   </prom:FactuRecibos>
```

Comment: Saludos compa, probé de esa manera y me dice: line 4: Element 'Facturecibos@MyCompany' with empty content type cannot have text or element content.

Comment: Eso significa que el tag FactuRecibos no puede llevar nada dentro... te tocará investigar qué es lo que espera.

Comment: Según me dijo el ingeniero es un string xml y me dio ese archivo en .txt que contiene el xml, esto dijo el Ing. según el documento funcional sobre el que está basado el desarrollo debe ser una llamada POST, no GET).hay un XML que se acaba pasando al servicio web.
prueba con SOAPUI, donde se puede configurar el servicio web, el método y donde debes crear un objeto Request donde vaya el XML que e pase.

Comment: Gracias!! Me oriento sobre como enviar la data desde SQL SERVER